# How to build shared library using CMake, starting from this (non working) Makefile example

Tags: php, c++, makefile, cmake, swig

I am writing a Makefile by hand to create a PHP extension lib using SWIG. I have the following directory structure:

```
wrappers/   # SWIG generated C++ wrappers and header
objects/    # I want to place my object files here
bin/        # I want to place my executable (shared lib) here
```

This is what my Makefile looks like:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-fPIC -c -Wall
INCLUDES=`php-config --includes` -Iwrappers
LDFLAGS=-shared
SOURCES=foo_wrap.cpp \
        foobar_wrap.cpp  \
        foofoobar_wrap.cpp   \
        foobarbar_wrap.cpp

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=php_foobarlib.so

all: wrappers/$(SOURCES) bin/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o objects/$(input)

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o objects/$(input)

clean:
    rm -rf *o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

When I run make at the command line, I get the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `foobar_wrap.cpp', needed by`all'. 
>   Stop.

I want to build the shared library using CMake instead. Could someone please post an outline of the CMakeLists file I need to create to build the shared library, taking into accounts the directory structure of the project - i.e. where I want the built objects and binaries to go.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yes all the files exist. The problem is with the locations. It is the directory structure of my project that is causing the (file not found) problems.

Comment: try: SOURCES=wrappers/foo_wrap.cpp wrappers/fo. .... and so on, remove wrappers/ from all:

Comment: @fritzone: Yes, thats what I had before, although that builds the object files, the object files were also being dumped into `wrappers/` which I dont want. I want to generate the object files and binaries in the folders I have specified.

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory

Comment: @fritzone: Do you want to post that as an answer?, its the closest to a solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in the `Makefile` the following:

```
SOURCES=wrappers/foo_wrap.cpp wrappers/fo. .... and so on,
```

and then remove `wrappers/` from `all:`

As observed by you, this will create the object files in the `wrappers` directory. In order to avoid that look at the [gcc/g++ option to place all object files into separate directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory) answer for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`wrappers/$(SOURCES)` expands to nonsense, prefixing only the first filename with the path.

Comment: Ok, so that explains the error message. So how do I fix my Makefile so that sources are kept in `wrappers` and object files and binaries are built into `objects` and `bin` respectively?