# Makefile when srcdir != objdir

Tags: c++, makefile

I modified the [gcc/g++ option to place all object files into separate directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory) posting for my scenario. However, returns error when running `make link`.

Project Tree

```
|--- bin
|    |--- main
|--- obj
|    |--- object1.o
|    |--- object2.o
|    |--- ...
|--- src
|    |--- source1.cpp
|    |--- source2.cpp
|    |--- ...
|--- main.cpp
```

Makefile

```
SRCDIR = ./src
OBJDIR = ./obj
BINDIR = ./bin
INCDIR = ./src

CC = g++

EXEC = main
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp main.cpp)
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))

compile: $(OBJ)

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

link:
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ)

clean:
    find -type f -name "$(EXEC)" -delete
    find -type f -name "*.o" -delete
    find -type f -name "*~" -delete
```

Eg.:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Source.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Source::hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Source.h

```
#include "Source.h"

#ifndef SOURCE_H
#define SOURCE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Source {

    public:
        static void hello();

};

#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Source.h"

void Source::hello() {
    cout << "Hello Makefile" << endl;
}
```

`make compile` ok! Create all objects (obj/*.o)

Problem: `make link`

Erro:

```
g++ -o main ./obj/Source.o ./obj/main.o
./obj/main.o: In function `Source::hello()':
Source.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Source::hello()'
```

I know the problem

`g++ -c src/Source.cpp -o obj/Source.o`

`g++ -c src/Source.cpp -o obj/main.o.`

I do not know how to solve.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: When you are linking, the linker needs to find all the references. It seems to not find the `Classes::functions()` function - which is probably not a problem in your makefile, but in the source file that contains (or SHOULD contain) the `Classes::functions()` - obviously, without seeing your source code, it's nearly impossible to say exactly what is wrong here.

Comment: Included my code in post

Comment: `Source.h` probably shouldn't have `#include "Source.h"` in it...

Comment: Strange. Your source.cpp says `Source::Hello` and then `Source::print` in main.cpp, which doesn't exist anywhere else - I'd expect to see a "missing" function, rather than a double declaration. I have a feeling you have edited your source in a way that "alters" the behaviour compares to your REAL source code.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce the problem, but I don't quite know how to fix it. Both `main.o` and `src/Source.o` are made from `src/Source.cpp` (you can see this when you do `make compile`

Comment: Knows another way to do a make separating srcdir and objdir?

Comment: I think I know WHY it's compiling everything to the same .o file - it's because you are using `$<` in the rule for `$(OBJ): $(SRC)`. I'm still trying to figure out what the fix is - I'm sure it's really trivial, but right now I can't see it.

Comment: I realized the problem `g++ -c src/Source.cpp -o obj/Source.o` and `g++ -c src/Source.cpp -o obj/main.o`. I do not know how to solve.

Comment: Don't `using namespace std;` in your header file ;-) Nor `#include <iostream>` since it's not needed in that header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the PERFECT solution, but this works:

```make
SRCDIR = ./src
OBJDIR = ./obj
BINDIR = ./bin
INCDIR = ./src

CC = g++

EXEC = main
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp main.cpp)
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))

CXX_FLAGS = -I $(INCDIR) -Wall

.PHONY : compile
compile: $(OBJ)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY : link
link: compile
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    find -type f -name "$(EXEC)" -delete
    find -type f -name "*.o" -delete
    find -type f -name "*~" -delete
```

Note that I've made an automatic rule to compile all the `SRCDIR` sources, and then a special rule for `main`, since `main` is not in the same directory, so the first rule doesn't work.

I also added `.PHONY` for `compile`, `link` and `clean`, as those are not "real targets", they are just names used to tell make what you want done. It doesn't matter, until at some point you happen to have a file called `compile`, `link` or `clean` in the directory - at that point, your makefile suddenly either fails to work correctly (e.g. it doesn't "compile", because there is a file called compile in your directory, and `compile` doesn't depend on anything else, so there is nothing to be done according to make).

(For my own benefit, I also added a dependency for `compile` to `link`, so I didn't have to type `make clean compile link`, but could use just `make clean link`).

As discussed in the comments, the problem is caused by `$<` being expanded to "the first element in the rule", which is always `srcdir/Source.cpp`, rather than "whatever source corresponds to the object file.

I think one could do something using for example `VPATH` or maybe `$(<F)` variables... But I can't figure out how right now.