# What do these symbols mean: $[@ , $@ , $<

Tags: makefile

In some `.mak` files I see lines like:

```
$(CC) $[@ $(CFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) $(DFLAGS)
```

I know that the `$` sign means the value of the variable... But what is `$[@` (where there is no variable)?

Other examples: `$[*` , `$^@`

And `$@ $<` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1892934/900394), in the lines:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) -c $(INC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Now I know that the last two lines mean to create the `.o` files in `ODIR` directory and the `.c` files in `SDIR` directory. But what's the essential meaning of `$@ $<`?

I couldn't find anything except [these apache-related results](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%5E%40) as examples, with no explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are automatic variables as described here : [GNU make : Automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

Also see this thread : [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Comment: If a question is a dupe then close it as one.