# g++ sometimes spits out .o files in my Home directory on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I have a build bash script in the folder of my code which spits out the .o files but, sometimes, I find duplicates in my Home directory.

What's causing this and how do I prevent this?

Here is my build script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm explorer-app
rm *.o
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -c *.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 *.o -fPIC -o explorer-app -L/usr/lib/SFML -L/usr/lib/Qt -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/SFML -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/Qt -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It's an honest problem I've never encountered before and it doesn't make sense

Comment: Could you update with the bash script? Or at least the part where you generate the .o?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the problem, the info you have posted, won't allow anyone to be able to help much

Comment: The information that you have provided is not sufficient to answer. But what you are observing may be possible due different value of pwd when compiling the code.

Comment: @Ritesh added script

Comment: The script seems fine. But on the safe side, add a command as the first file to change pwd, something like cd srdir, srcdir represents the location of srcfile. That will eliminate the chances of o files being created anywhere else. But the best solution will be to use makefile. Please read the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  , especially the answer from anon.

Comment: @Maverick: Can you try executing your script from different locations and see if you are able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Where are you executing the make file?

Comment: @138 same dir as the script

Comment: running rm *.o at the end might be a quick n dirty fix, not sure if this is what you want though. Have yout though of using a makefile not a bash script?

Comment: The solution I'm looking for should pertain to using bash scripts. On that note I also do not like adding more dependencies than necessary. Makefiles are fossils and have convoluted syntax. Bash is simple and effective for most projects.

Comment: Since you are inclined to using the bash script, You can add few thing to your script, the first command will be to change the present working directory to what you really want it to be. Second when you generate the .o files, do them inside particular folder, and not along the src files.  These 2 things will prevent any leakage of .o files. But still I am out of idea that how your .o files leaked.

Comment: I've added the 'cd .' command at the top of the script. We'll see if that makes a difference. It is strange.

Comment: cd . will not help. cd . will always set pwd to where you are. You need to add cd <the exactpath where the code is>.

Comment: right I always run the bash script inside the same dir as the script. Just for completeness sake I'll make it the absolute path. Still does not address the problem completely.

Comment: Adding an absolute path did something different. Instead of spilling .o files in the root dir, some extraneous .o files are littered in the parent directory where I run the script from! @Ritesh

Comment: Can you specify what you meant by root dir  and parent dir. It is not possible for .o files to get created out of dir if you have added cd <srcppath> at the top of your script. Is it possible to paste the updated script?

Comment: Root dir: `~/` aka Home

Comment: Parent dir. The literal directory above the one I'm building in.

Comment: Script did not change except I added a `cd ~/Code/project/` path. The script works and builds. Sometimes `.o` files appear in ~/Code/`.