# How to force GNU make to recompile the same object file used in two targets with different FLAGS

Tags: c++, c, makefile, clearcase, ld

Suppose you have have a `makefile` containing two targets as in the following:

```
# targetA
X86CPPTARGET += targetA
targetA,SRCS = FILEA.cpp  FILEB.cpp commonFile.cpp
targetA.so,DEPSOL = libUsedByCommon1.cpp
targetA,CPPFLAGS += -Ifakeinclude -std=c++11

# tartargetBgetA
X86CPPTARGET += targetB
targetB,SRCS = FILEC.cpp  FILED.cpp commonFile.cpp
targetA.so,DEPSOL = libUsedByCommon2.cpp
targetB,CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

`targetA` and `targetB` share a file, namely, `commonFile.cpp` which contains a number of `#include`d headers.
`commonFile.o` is created only once by GNU make and reused during the compilation of `targetB`.

The CPPFLAGS present in `targetA` makes the compiler use an include that contains more symbols that the one that is in the default include directory.  `libUsedByCommon2` does not export all the additional symbols that are contained in the header in the `fakeinclude` directory and at link time, this results in `undefined reference`.

The workaround I am usingat the moment is to create a symbolic link to `commonFile.cpp` and use that in my `makefile` in only one of the target.

```
# targetA
X86CPPTARGET += targetA
targetA,SRCS = FILEA.cpp  FILEB.cpp commonFile.cpp
targetA.so,DEPSOL = libUsedByCommon1.cpp
targetA,CPPFLAGS += -Ifakeinclude -std=c++11

# tartargetBgetA
X86CPPTARGET += targetB
targetB,SRCS = FILEC.cpp  FILED.cpp **commonFile_symbolic_link.cpp**
targetA.so,DEPSOL = libUsedByCommon2.cpp
targetB,CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Is there a cleaner solution to this problem?
Is there a way to force GNU make to recompile `commonFile.cpp`  when a different include path is being used?

Comment: You need two target object files with different names.

Comment: I suspect you always have to give the object file different names. One way I do it is to call `$(MAKE)` from the `Makefile` after setting a name-extension variable so I don't duplicate all my targets.

Comment: That what I also suppose, but it is strange to me that make does not recompile something for which I am clearly asking to use different compiler options.

Comment: This is asking for trouble. Why not just target 2 different folders?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk what do you mean exactly?

Comment: [gcc/g++ option to place all object files into separate directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory#1892934)

Answer (score 3):

You could create two new targets who are dependent on the same C file with different build commands like the following example...

```
commonFileA.o: commonFile.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -FlagsA

commonFileB.o: commonFile.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -FlagsB
```

You can then use "commonFileA.o" as a dependency to link in the version with those particular flags etc...

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try to compile the same source file but with two different output object files:

```
a0.o: MYFLAGS := foo bar
a0.o: a.c
a1.o: MYFLAGS := baz cux
a1.o: a.c
```

And then, for the depending targets, use either `a0.o` or `a1.o` as prerequisite.

Answer (score 2):

One way I have done this is to set a variable and then recursively call `make` with a specific target. One advantage of this method is you can specify your targets only once.

This is an *incomplete* extract to show the technique:

```
all: debug release

debug:
    @echo -e "\n====== BUILDING DEBUG PROGRAM ======\n"
    @FLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS_DBG)" SUFFIX="-debug" $(MAKE) general

release:
    @echo -e "\n====== BUILDING RELEASE PROGRAM ======\n"
    @FLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS_REL)" $(MAKE) general

general: $(PROGRAM)$(SUFFIX)

$(PROGRAM)$(SUFFIX): $(SRC)/program.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^
```