# How do i change .o and .exe file locations to seperate folders in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

All I want is to make a different folder for .o files and .exe files and .cpp files and store .o and .exe files into the respective folders, right after building.

- Is that possible?
- If yes, how?

Comment: It depends on what linker (and compiler) you are using.

Comment: @Lundin so this is not IDE specific? I just want to make it such that every time I build a cpp file, it stores the .o and .exe files away from the .cpp files, since it looks a bit weird.

Comment: I don't know how you've managed that in the first place. Opening up a default gcc Codeblocks project I get source in the main folder then binaries below \bin\debug and object files below \obj\debug.

Comment: Does this solve the problem..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory

Comment: @Lundin, maybe my code::blocks installation was messed up, if you can help in any way, it would be great.

Comment: @Noah, not really. I dont understand what he did, and I do not know what makefile and such means

Comment: Simple re-install it and try the default settings, then take it from there?