# How to specify output file directory when using gcc -c option?

Tags: gcc

I tried to compile .c file to .o and it is located in specific directory. The similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814270/gcc-g-option-to-place-all-object-files-into-separate-directory) but this is not what I'm looking for.

For some reason, I don't want to use `-o` option now. I'm using `-c` option. The default output path of `gcc -c` is current directory. I tried to redirect it into some specific directory such as `/objs`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `For some reason, I don't want to use -o option now` Sooo for what reason? `The similar question is here but this is not what I'm looking for.` Why isn't it? Doesn't ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814344/9072753 answer it? `I tried to redirect it into some specific directory` What and how have you tried it exactly?

Comment: I will use link script to link all of the object files later

Comment: How does using a link script _later_ to link all object files prevent you from using `-o` option?

Comment: To use linker script is the second stage in my case and it will use -o option. Now my question is in first stage, try to use -c option to generate object files in specific directory

Comment: Great - so use `-o` option with gcc to specify output file location. Or use ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814344/9072753 answer. (But overall, move to cmake, bazel, scons or other build systems that were made specifically to figure such stuff for you). I do not understand - I still fail to see what does prevent you from using `-o` option.

Comment: But I don't want to link all needed functions at first (`-o`)

Comment: If you use `-c` no linking is done at all, and in that case adding `-o` does nothing more than specify where the output object file should go.  To be clear, what's being suggested is `gcc -c -o /objs/foo.o foo.c`.

Comment: It seems like maybe you have some confusion over what `-o` actually does.

Comment: yes, ur right. I has some confusion about it.